# MySQL Query Browser Error Data truncated for column

Tags: mysql, vb.net

This is my code and I dont know why I'm getting this Error in my visual studio 2013 and my data base is MySQL Query Browser:

***"Additional information: ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.1.34-community]Data truncated for column 'userid' at row 1"***

If a = "New" Then
            Dim sqlstring As String
            sqlstring = "INSERT into users(username, userid, usertype, remarks)values('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & ComboBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "')"
            cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand(sqlstring, cnn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            reset()
            disable()
            btn3()
        End If

Comment: The issue is most likely that the value you passed for that column is too long for the column definition. Apart from that, NEVER use string concatenation to insert values into SQL code like that.  ALWAYS [use parameters](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html).

Comment: Also, `Odbc` should be your last choice for an ADO.NET provider.  If you're using MySQL then, if you can, you should download Connector/Net from the MySQL web site and use that.  `MySqlClient` is a MySQL-specific provider, just as `SqlClient` is specific to SQL Server.  You can also download some MySQL-specific tools for VS that support EF and such.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the total length of the characters you are passing exceeded the length defined by column `userid`. Aside from that, mysql has its own managed provider called `MySqlClient` and this is the one you should be using.

A much better way to good practice programming is to paramaterized your query. Example below is at least your good starting point:

```
Dim connectionString As String = "..your connection string here..."
Using SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
   Using sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand()
      sqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT into users(username, userid, usertype, remarks) VALUES (@username, @userid, @usertype, @remarks)"
      sqlCommand.Connection = SQLConnection
      sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
      sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox1.Text)
      sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", TextBox2.Text)
      sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usertype", ComboBox1.Text)
      sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remarks", TextBox4.Text)
      SQLConnection.Open()
      sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   End Using
End Using
```